# Why don't this similar functions throw the same error?

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, return-type

I have two functions with the same return types:

```
char * getRandomWord(char wordlist[WORDLIST_LENGTH][WORD_LENGTH]) {
    int random = rand() % WORDLIST_LENGTH;
    return wordlist[random];
}

char * revealInString(char * s, int * r) {
    size_t strLength = strlen(s);
    char revealedString[strLength + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {
        revealedString[i] = '_';
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {
        if (r[i] != NULL) {
            int positionToReveal = r[i];
            revealedString[positionToReveal] = s[positionToReveal];
        }
    }
    revealedString[strLength - 1] = '\0';
    return revealedString;
}
```

The first one works without problems, while my IDE (CLion) shows a problem in the second one: `Value escapes the local scope`.

Why does the second function show that error, while the first one also returns an array of characters without problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `char revealedString[N]` defines a VLA (a C99 feature) that is allocated on the stack.

...but your `revealInString` function then returns a pointer to stack-allocated memory. This is a bug: when your function returns the stack is popped, so `revealedString` now points to invalid memory.

In comparison, your first example returns a pointer to memory allocated prior to the function being called.

While functions that allocate on the stack, then return, can work (provided the caller makes no further calls), it is a very bad idea because it depends on undefined-behaviour.

You have two options for fixing the issue:

1. Have the caller allocate the VLA on the stack prior to calling `revealInString`
2. Allocate the array on the heap (with `calloc` or `malloc`) and ensure the caller calls `free` when they're done.

Example 1:

```
char revealedStringBuffer[ strlen(s) + 1 ];
revealInString( revealedStringBuffer, r ); // and change `revealInString` to return void
```

Example 2:

```
char * revealInString(char * s, int * r) {
    size_t strLength = strlen(s);
    char* revealedString = calloc( strLength + 1, sizeof(char) );
    if( revealedString == NULL ) die("calloc failure.");

    for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {
        revealedString[i] = '_';
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {
        if (r[i] != NULL) {
            int positionToReveal = r[i];
            revealedString[positionToReveal] = s[positionToReveal];
        }
    }
    revealedString[strLength - 1] = '\0';
    return revealedString;
}

// Usage:
char* revealedString = revealInString( s, r );
free( revealedString );
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither of them returns an array. They return a pointer (to a `char`).

In the second function the returned pointer points into a local variable. Local variables are destroyed when the function returns, so the returned pointer becomes invalid. This is why the compiler warns you about it.

In the first case, you return a pointer that was passed in by the caller, so if it was valid then, it'll still be valid when the function returns.